# What would you say?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?
'I smelled that our dinner was burning.'

I don't think I've heard that 'smell' as a verb is followed by that-clause.
What do you think?

Comment: Provide full context, the entire paragraph, to understand why *that* was used.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's correct.  Smelled is used in the way that "saw" can be used for sight.

```
I saw that our dinner was burning
```

If my sentence makes sense to you, then having "smelled" as the verb serves the same function as "saw." The only difference between your example and mine is the sense which is used to detect a burning dinner: smelling versus seeing, both of which are possible.